# When do you use UML direct associations vs. normal associations

Tags: java, class, uml

I have a class diagram like it is shown in the picture.

[image]
There is a Controller that has some TopicLoaderIF and several TopicReaderIF classes. The TopicLoaderIF creates a series of TopicIF upon request from the Controller. Then the Controller forwards these TopicIF to the correct TopicReaderIF. Let's not enter in weather these model is correct or not but in the relationship between them.

The thing is that I have been trying to model this as an UML class diagram but I am stuck thinking on the kind of relation between the Controller and the TopicIF (in red), if there should be any in the diagram. Further more, I am also not sure if it is correct that all three, the TopicLoaderIF, the Controller and the TopicReaderIF, have a direct associations to TopicIF. Should they be just a normal association, without the arrow?

I would appreciate any advice you may give me regarding this diagram.

Comment: Interaces are abstract. So you can not compose them like with `TopcReaderIF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigability expresses `A` can see `B` if there's an arrow from `A` to `B`. In a rough sketch these arrows can be helpful, but are not mandatory. If the arrow is not present, both classes could see each other, but must not. When implementing such an unspecified association you will judge at the needs and only implement needed references (if `B` has no need to see `A` you would not implement a reference).

Once you are going into detailed design, you will start using role names towards the ends. This makes perfectly clear how navigation will work.

**TL;DR** When sketching, use arrows. Once starting with details, replace them with role names.